# Getting error while trying to migrate to Angular 9 : Undecorated classes with DI migration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I am trying to migrate from Angular 8 to Angular 9 and getting below error on step: **Undecorated classes with DI migration.**

> Could not migrate all undecorated classes that use dependency
>       injection. Some project targets could not be analyzed due to
>       TypeScript program failures.
>
> Error: error TS100: src\app\app.module.ts(107,25): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
>         Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'combineReducers' was called in 'appReducers'
>           'appReducers' references 'modelReducer' at src\app\store\reducers\index.ts(13,10)
>             'modelReducer' calls 'combineReducers' at src\app\store\reducers\model.ts(25,29).

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You more than likely need to decorate any classes that are using DI with `@Injectable()`

ex:

```
@Injectable()
class MyClass {
  constructor(someService: SomeService) {...}
}
```

I personally am holding off on working with 9 until it's GA (due to previous experiences with major releases). But, "DI" and "undecorated classes" screams "you're missing the Injectable decorator" to me.

Are you going from 8.x to 9?